# Error Is not a function en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo un html con unos campos y un boton: al apretar el boton quiero que cree un objeto Persona y muestre con las funciones del objeto los datos introducidos.

El error es: InteractVisual.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: per.getNombre is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.GetData (InteractVisual.js:15)
GetData @ InteractVisual.js:15

Codigo de Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Persona.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/InteractVisual.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Nombre: </p>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="Nombre">
    <p>Apellido: </p>
    <input type="text" name="secondName" id="Apellido">
    <p>CI: </p>
    <input type="text" name="ci" id="CI">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubir">Enviar</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Codigo De InteractVisual.js:

```js
var TxtNombre, TxtApellido, TxtCi, btnSubir;

window.onload = init;

function init() {
    TxtNombre = document.getElementById('Nombre');
    TxtApellido = document.getElementById('Apellido');
    TxtCi = document.getElementById('CI');
    btnSubir = document.getElementById('btnSubir');
    btnSubir.addEventListener('click', GetData, false);
}

function GetData() {
    var per = new Persona(TxtNombre.value, TxtApellido.value, TxtCi.value);
    alert(per.getNombre());
    alert(per.getApellido());
    alert(per.getCI());
}
```

Codigo de Persona.js:

```js
var Nombre, Apellido, CI;

class Persona {

    constructor(nombre, apellido, ci) {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Apellido = apellido;
        this.CI = ci;
    }

    //Funciones Getter y Setter
    get getNombre() {
        return this.Nombre;
    }

    set setNombre(nombre) {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
    }

    get getApellido() {
        return this.Apellido;
    }

    set setApellido(apellido) {
        this.Apellido = apellido;
    }

    get getCI() {
        return this.CI;
    }

    set setCI(ci) {
        this.CI = ci;
    }
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los `get` y los `set` se usan para definir *propiedades*. Por lo tanto, **no usan paréntesis** para invocarse.

Cambia tu por `GetData( )` por:

```
function GetData( ) {
  var per = new Persona( TxtNombre.value, TxtApellido.value, TxtCi.value );
  alert( per.getNombre );
  alert( per.getApellido );
  alert( per.getCI );
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)